Trying to implement a customer circular reference handler in symfony 6.4
I have an Asset object - Which as a creator object as a property - and the Creator object has a 'featured_asset' as a property.   But this is causing a circular reference error in Symfony Serializer.  I have tried setting #[MaxDepth(1)] on the featured asset but it doesnt make a difference, so I want to implement a custom CircularReferenceHandler.
I have these lines in config/packages/framework.yaml:
serializer:
    circular_reference_handler: App\Serializer\CircularReferenceHandler
    enabled: true

And in App\Serializer\CircularReferenceHandler.php:
<?php

namespace App\Serializer;

class CircularReferenceHandler
{
    public function __invoke($object)
    {
        return $object->getId();
    }
}

The way I am serializing the object is with $this->json in SearchController:
return $this->json($this->buildResponse($results), 200, [], ['groups' => $this->scope, 'max_depth' => 1]);
But it seems to have an issue with me adding 'serializer' in framework.yaml, becauese I get this error:
There is no extension able to load the configuration for "serializer" (in "/var/www/html/config/packages/framework.yaml"). Looked for namespace "serializer", found ""framework", "nelmio_cors", "fos_elastica", "doctrine", "doctrine_migrations", "fos_rest", "security"" in /var/www/html/config/packages/framework.yaml (which is being imported from "/var/www/html/src/Kernel.php").

I think I must be missing something.  I ran composer install symfony/serializer.  This is my composer.json:
{
"type": "project",
"license": "proprietary",
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"prefer-stable": true,
"require": {
    "php": "8.3",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "ext-dom": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "ext-memcached": "*",
    "ext-simplexml": "*",
    "ext-zip": "*",
    "doctrine/annotations": "^2.0",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.11",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.3",
    "doctrine/orm": "*",
    "friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "*",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^3.6",
    "nelmio/cors-bundle": "^2.4",
    "symfony/console": "6.4.*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "6.4.*",
    "symfony/expression-language": "6.4.*",
    "symfony/flex": "^2",
    "symfony/form": "6.4.*",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "6.4.*",
    "symfony/http-foundation": "6.4.*",
    "symfony/process": "6.4.*",
    "symfony/runtime": "6.4.*",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "6.4.*",
    "symfony/serializer": "6.4.*",
    "symfony/validator": "6.4.*",
    "symfony/yaml": "6.4.*"
},
"config": {
    "allow-plugins": {
        "php-http/discovery": true,
        "symfony/flex": true,
        "symfony/runtime": true
    },
    "sort-packages": true
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"replace": {
    "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php73": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php74": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php80": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php81": "*"
},
"scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
        "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
        "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
    },
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ]
},
"conflict": {
    "symfony/symfony": "*"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony": {
        "allow-contrib": false,
        "require": "6.4.*"
    }
},
"require-dev": {
    "rector/rector": "^1.0"
}

}
What can I do to fix this? Really I would love not to do this at all and just be able to set the MaxDepth and have the featured_asset only display top level properties.
Please help.

You are missing the framework key in your config/packages/framework.yaml file. It should look like:
framework:
    serializer:
        # ...

You may execute php bin/console config:dump-reference framework to display the default configuration or php bin/console debug:config framework for your actual configuration.
Official documentation:

Debug Configuration Reference
Framework Configuration Reference
How to Use the Serializer (with samples of  YAML configuration)

